# Google Drive storage mismatch

Tags: google-drive

I have a paid 100GB Google Drive plan. It is reporting that I am at 99% capacity.

According to the the storage both within the desktop and web application, I have used 90.53GB within Drive.

[image: storage used]

My Drive is mapped to my OS X filesystem, and when fully synched it reports only 61.28GB used.

[image: file system]

So what is going on here? I need to do a cleanup but cannot account for the 30GB difference.

Comment: Do you have a very large number of very small files? Every file has a certain minimum storage overhead, and that may be different on different filesystems.

Comment: There is also a "Trash" folder. Did you empty that?

Comment: @Al E. Wow I fell for that one when XP came out. My trash did have a lot of very large files in it, and I have emptied it. It didn't seem to make a difference. Strange.

Comment: @Al E. It has updated now. Looks like it takes some time to update the available storage after a large delete. Please add as the answer & I will accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most likely culprit is your Google Drive [*Trash*](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375102) folder. (*Note:* this name is localized. In the UK it's called "Bin". No matter what it's called it has the same function.)

[image: Google Drive menu]

The stuff in there will count against your quota. Empty that manually and it should help. Note that it may take a day or two for your quota to be updated.

Also, Google Drive keeps revisions of your files. ([Anything older than 30 days and 100 revisions is subject to having older revisions removed](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045).) Those revisions also count against your quota, though they won't actually appear on your local drive.

(h/t to [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n))

Comment: As of March 2016, the item in the menu is called `bin`, not trash.

Comment: @kontur: Nope. In the U.S. it's "Trash". (I created that screen shot yesterday.) In countries like the U.K. it's named "Bin".