# Why does Google Drive think I'm using so much space?

Tags: google-drive

[image]

When I click on the little blue `i` to view my quota there is no way there's 7GB worth of used space. There's not a ton of revisions. All my photos take up zero space because I bought a Pixel XL. All my docs are Google Docs not Word Docs so they don't take up any space. The biggest files I have are a few PDFs which are manuals for my dishwasher or clothes dryer. They start at 8MB and get smaller.

[image]

That's the top of my quota list. How can I find the problem files? If it's a mistake, how can I request Google to reindex my GDrive and fix the limit?

Comment: Your trash also counts towards your quota, so check there as well.

Comment: I did have a lot of stuff in there.I just emptied it. For now, it still says I'm using 7GB but I'll give it time to see if it updates to a lower number.

Comment: It only took a minute or two but it did update. Now it says I'm using 31MB. Thanks. If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Also: [Google Drive storage mismatch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69184/354)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to check your trash as well because that also counts towards your quota and doesn't auto-empty.

After emptying the trash, it could take a couple of minutes before the *X GB used* number is updated.

Comment: I really wish the Quota page indicated how much space the trash can was taking up. If there was a "Trash: 6.9GB" there would be no confusion.

Comment: _and wait a couple of minutes for the usage number to update_ - I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: While double checking this I noticed that I still had files in my trash from 2012.  Seems silly to not auto-clean at least once a year.