# How do I free up space in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I've reached the point my drive is almost full. Seemed easy enough to handle by deleting stuff. But it's not so simple. Deleting many large files (2+ GB worth) did nothing to change the amount of storage I'm using and I have no idea why. The files are gone, but they seem to still be taking up space somehow.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to free up space on their Google Drive, how do I do it?

Comment: Duplicate questions: [Google Drive storage mismatch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69184/109353), [Why does Google Drive think I'm using so much space?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106953/109353)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive storage mismatch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69184/google-drive-storage-mismatch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted files and folders from your Google Drive go to ***Trash*** which is also part of total storage. So go to Trash icon and delete files from there also. You will be able to see the available space after that.

[image]

<sup><sup>Image source: Google</sup></sup>

Note, once you delete any item from Trash that cannot be recovered. It will be deleted permanently.

Comment: Thanks! Just found years worth of stuff I've deleted...